# CSS Background Image Not Displaying ( using HTML5 Boilerplate)

Tags: css, html, background-image

Is there any reason for when using html5 boilerplate to set up a website using

```
   body {
      background-image: url(../images/beach.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

in the css won't load an image for me, but using just

```
   body {
      background: url(../images/beach.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `background-image`, you can only use this property to set the background image. Values that belong to other properties cannot be set. In this case, you're trying to set values for properties which do not belong to the `background-image` property.

This is possible if you're using the `background` property, which you can use to set any `background`-related property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-image:url(../images/beach.png) center center fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` is a directive to set only the file of background image.
Other properties can be set with these directives:

`background-color 
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position`

`background` only is a shorthand that permits to use one or more directive above.

> The background shorthand property sets all the background properties in one declaration.

[More infos on w3school site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must use double quotation.
background-image: url("paper.gif");